# Conditional extraction of a substring from a string

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a DataFrame with a column that is an object and contains the full address in one of the following formats:

1. 'street name, building number',
2. 'city, street, building number',
3. 'city, district, street, building number'.

Regardless of the format I need to extract the name of the street and copy it to a new column. I cannot attach the original DF since all the information is in Russian. I've created a dummy DF instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'address':['new york city, the bronx borough, willis avenue, building 34',
                   'town of salem, main street, building 105',
                   'second boulevard, 12'],
                   'street':0})
```

**N.B.** Different parts of one string are always separated by one comma. The substring with the street name in it always contains one of the words: 'street', 'avenue', 'boulevard'.

After several hours of Googling I've come up with something like this but to no avail:

```
street_list = ['street', 'avenue', 'boulevard']

for row in df:
    for x in street_list:
        if df.loc[row, 'address'].split(', ')[0].contains(x):
            df.loc[row, 'street'] = df.loc[row, 'address'].split(', ')[0]
        elif df.loc[row, 'address'].split(', ')[1].contains(x):
            df.loc[row, 'street'] = df.loc[row, 'address'].split(', ')[1]
        elif df.loc[row, 'address'].split(', ')[2].contains(x):
            df.loc[row, 'street'] = df.loc[row, 'address'].split(', ')[2]
```

This code doesn't work for me. Is it possible to tweak it somehow so that it works(or maybe you know a better solution)?

Please let me know if any additional information is required.

Comment: I can't seem to find a question here.

Comment: The code that I've attached is not working. Is it possible to tweak it to extract only the names of the street from the full address and copy it to a new column?

Comment: Can you try ` df['street'] = df.address.apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[-2])`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that there can be 1, 2 or 3 comma separated substrings after the name of the street.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand: 
1. The streets could be in a couple of positions in the comma separated values depending on the length. 
2. The streets has an additional substring check.

In the below code: 
Point 1 is represented by the streetMap 
Point 2 is represented by the 'any' condition

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'address':['new york city, the bronx borough, willis avenue, building 34',
                   'town of salem, main street, building 105',
                   'second boulevard, 12'],
                   'street':0})

streetMap = {2:0,3:1,4:2} # Map of length of items to location of street.

street_list = ['street', 'avenue', 'boulevard']

addresses = df['address']
streets = []
for address in addresses:
    items = address.split(', ')
    streetCandidate = items[streetMap[len(items)]]
    street = streetCandidate if any([s in streetCandidate for s in street_list]) else "NA"
    streets.append(street)
df['street'] = streets

print(df)
```

Output:

```
0  new york city, the bronx borough, willis avenu...     willis avenue
1           town of salem, main street, building 105       main street
2                               second boulevard, 12  second boulevard
```